# Why I get TypeError: dialog.addDialogTrigger is not a function?

Tags: node.js, botframework

My bot is not working anymore : if I send any message to the "/" dialog or other dialogs (for instance "/menu").
I always get the same error "TypeError: dialog.addDialogTrigger is not a function"

Bot Info :

1. SDK Platform: Node.js
2. SDK Version: botbuilder 3.14.0

Deployment Environment:

1. Azure Bot Service
2. local development with Emulator

Code Example

```
bot.dialog('menu', require("./dialogs/menu"))
    .triggerAction({
        matches: /^#menuderungly$/i
    });
```

Any idea how to cope with that ?
Many thanks for your help !

Comment: The second parameter of `bot.dialog` should be a dialog or `IDialogWaterfallStep`, what is your `dialogs/menu`? I didn't see any `dialog.addDialogTrigger` here.

Comment: What is the format of the exports from `./dialogs/menu`? Also, can you show additional code on the instantiation of the `UniversalBot` and the other code related to your `bot` and the registering of dialogs?

Comment: for debugging, put a `console.log(bot.dialog('menu', require('./dialogs/menu')))` and see what is the result. Does that actually have `triggerAction` function

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to call a dialog that is on another file. In that case you would have to declare the dialog in that file just like any other NodeJs function:

parentDialog.js

```
var childrenDialogs = require('./childrenDialogs'); 
...
...
// this is where the base dialog handles the conversation over to another dialog
bot.dialog('/', childrenDialogs.childDialog1);
```

childrenDialogs.js:

```
exports.childDialog1 = (session) => {
    // something in this dialog
}
```

I hope this helps. Cheers! :)